# SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) Setup Failed (0x800B010C)

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssms

I am trying to install SSMS on my Windows 10 machine. However, any version 18.0 or greater gives me an error:

> A certificate was explicitly revoked by its issuer (0x800B010C).

With version 18.0, the installer executable lists a revoked certificate in its properties, but the newer versions do not.

I have tried installing the solution [here](https://github.com/Aftnet/RetriX/issues/38) but no luck, still the same error. I have run all Windows Updates and tried disabling my AV (BitDefender).

It may be worth noting that version 17.x installs fine, with no issue.

Here is the log file:

```
[39B8:1E38][2020-11-21T16:21:24]i000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action started
[3A48:1640][2020-11-21T16:21:24]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[3A48:1640][2020-11-21T16:21:24]w363: Could not create system restore point, error: 0x80070422. Continuing...
[3A48:1640][2020-11-21T16:21:24]i000: Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Temp\{a83fd35c-47e3-4877-b7aa-427fc7de02c7}\.be\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{a83fd35c-47e3-4877-b7aa-427fc7de02c7}\SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe'
[3A48:1640][2020-11-21T16:21:24]i320: Registering bundle dependency provider: {a83fd35c-47e3-4877-b7aa-427fc7de02c7}, version: 15.0.18358.0
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:27]e000: Error 0x800b010c: Failed authenticode verification of payload: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:27]e000: Error 0x800b010c: Failed to verify signature of payload: HelpViewer2_3
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:27]e310: Failed to verify payload: HelpViewer2_3 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b010c. Deleting file.
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:27]e000: Error 0x800b010c: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3
[39B8:3D94][2020-11-21T16:21:27]e314: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3 from working path: C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Temp\{a83fd35c-47e3-4877-b7aa-427fc7de02c7}\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b010c.
[39B8:3D94][2020-11-21T16:21:27]e349: Application requested retry of payload: HelpViewer2_3, encountered error: 0x800b010c. Retrying...
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:30]e000: Error 0x800b010c: Failed authenticode verification of payload: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:30]e000: Error 0x800b010c: Failed to verify signature of payload: HelpViewer2_3
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:30]e310: Failed to verify payload: HelpViewer2_3 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b010c. Deleting file.
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:30]e000: Error 0x800b010c: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3
[39B8:3D94][2020-11-21T16:21:30]e314: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3 from working path: C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Temp\{a83fd35c-47e3-4877-b7aa-427fc7de02c7}\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b010c.
[39B8:3D94][2020-11-21T16:21:30]e349: Application requested retry of payload: HelpViewer2_3, encountered error: 0x800b010c. Retrying...
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:33]e000: Error 0x800b010c: Failed authenticode verification of payload: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:33]e000: Error 0x800b010c: Failed to verify signature of payload: HelpViewer2_3
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:33]e310: Failed to verify payload: HelpViewer2_3 at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\.unverified\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b010c. Deleting file.
[3A48:38B0][2020-11-21T16:21:33]e000: Error 0x800b010c: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3
[39B8:3D94][2020-11-21T16:21:33]e314: Failed to cache payload: HelpViewer2_3 from working path: C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Temp\{a83fd35c-47e3-4877-b7aa-427fc7de02c7}\HelpViewer2_3, error: 0x800b010c.
[39B8:1E38][2020-11-21T16:21:33]e000: Error 0x800b010c: Failed while caching, aborting execution.
[3A48:1640][2020-11-21T16:21:33]i330: Removed bundle dependency provider: {a83fd35c-47e3-4877-b7aa-427fc7de02c7}
[3A48:1640][2020-11-21T16:21:33]i352: Removing cached bundle: {a83fd35c-47e3-4877-b7aa-427fc7de02c7}, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{a83fd35c-47e3-4877-b7aa-427fc7de02c7}\
[39B8:1E38][2020-11-21T16:21:33]e000: MainViewModel.OnBundleAction: Bundle action failed: A certificate was explicitly revoked by its issuer (0x800B010C)
[39B8:1E38][2020-11-21T16:21:33]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x800b010c, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No
[39B8:2990][2020-11-21T16:21:39]i000: MainViewModel.OpenUrl: Opening url: C:\Users\Adam\AppData\Local\Temp\SsmsSetup\SSMS-Setup-ENU_20201121162122.log
```

Comment: I have the same problem at least you guide me to install an older version 17.9 and it worked for me thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Uninstall sql server

step 2: Restart your PC,

step 3: Download in sql server in microsoft offical web page,

step 4: Download finished ,

step 5: Download and install [sql server in version 18.11.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15)